# How to include an html file code on clicking on a <li> using ajax and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have these elements in my html code :

```
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li data-file='home'><a>Home</a></li>
  <li data-file='contact'><a>Contact</a></li>
   ..
   ..
</ul>
```

and I have a `<div>` called content:

```
<div class='content'>
   //Homepage Content
</div>
```

Then I use Javascript to get the content of the clicked `<li>` using `data-file` and then add .html for it so it become like this contact.html .

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
                   if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                       document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                   }
                   else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                      alert('There was an error 400');
                   }
                   else {
                       alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
                   }
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true); // file is the variable 'contact.html'
            xmlhttp.send();
```

But I get an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: The error is clear `document.getElementById('content')` is returning `null`. That's because you are looking for an element with ID "content", while you probably want to `getElemenetByClassName`.

Comment: `getElementById` will get you an element with a specific ID. Your element doesn't have the ID `content`, it has a class with that name. Either get the element by its class name or set its ID to `content`.

Comment: Thanks , the error is gone , But the content of the "content" div didn't change , why is that ?

Answer (score 2):

Change your HTML to have an element with the specified **ID**

```
<div id='content'>
   //Homepage Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , the error is gone , But the content of the "content" div didn't change , why is that ?

Comment: I guess now the question is what's contained in `xmlhttp.responseText`.  I would console.log this and see.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class='content'>
   //Homepage Content
</div>
```

Above should be :

```
<div id='content'>
   //Homepage Content
</div>
```

Because here `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` you are access the element using the ID attribute

Comment: Thanks , the error is gone , But the content of the "content" div didn't change , why is that ?

Comment: Console log this `xmlhttp.responseText`. Is it contains anything or is there any error in console

Comment: I include the response in a div which has the homepage content , I get this message in the console : XHR finished loading: GET "http://mywebsite/contact.html".